# SQL - Trouble counting values

Tags: sql

I have a Database named 'IDMS' and it has two columns named 'Table' and 'Column'.
I Need to do a simple query, list the values in 'Column' with a count of duplicates.

I tried this

```
Select `'Colum', Count(*)
From IDMS
GROUP by 'Column';`
```

and not joy.  I have tried differing variations of that select and it's not working.

Can anyone assist?

-Ron

Comment: Yes,somebody can assist, but could you please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question but if you use reserved names you can just put it []

If you need to know the column/table duplicated, had a the column [table]
and if you need to filter it you can just use having like @mimi said

```
Select 
[Column], 
Count(*),
CASE WHEN Count(*) > 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END as IsDuplicated 
From IDMS
GROUP by [Column];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you should remove the quotes (') around your "Column" column (I assume its a column from your table and you dont want a fixed 'Column' value as return). Also there is a spelling difference between your first Colum, and second Colum**N** values; so I will asume first field is named Column1 and second, Column2.

Second, to add the required condition to your query you should use `HAVING` clause with the desired requirement. For example, if you want result that have more than 1 occurrence of Column2 column in your table:

```
SELECT Column1, COUNT(Column2)
FROM IDMS
GROUP BY Column1
HAVING COUNT(Column2) > 1;
```